# Adding element to Dom set dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, css

In `.html` file I have somthing like this

```
<div [hidden]="visible">
    <div id='previewImg'></div>
</div>
```

in `.js` file I would like add `img` element to div with `id='previewImg'`

```
 onClick() {
    this.listImage = this.imageService.getImage();
    let mySpan = document.createElement('span');
    mySpan.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', this.listImage[0],
      '" title="', '"/>'
    ].join('');
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('previewImg').appendChild(mySpan).style.border = "3px solid";
    }, 0);
  }
```

also set style css to div

```
div#previewImg {
    border: 3px solid salmon;
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

I set max height and hight to div and i thought that loaded image also will have max-height and max-width dimension but loaded image goes beyond div boundaries.
My question is how to make that loaded image would have smaller or equal dimension div? How to customize the loaded image to diva dimensions ? Original img have 500x400 px and excced div dimension.

Comment: have you try set `100%` for both of your img `width` and `height`??

Comment: Anami I would to set image inside div as not to exceed its dimensions. But image is loaded with original size to div.

Comment: could you create fiddle or codepen ?

Comment: What is the resulting html? Because there is probally something off there

Comment: @Martijn result of html is loaded img to div element.

Comment: No, I mean the actual source. Excecute it, go to you console, view the result (not what you want to do to, what it *is*). And copy that to your answer :)

Comment: @Martijn i would set some style to loaded img that it fit in diva dimensions

Comment: @Martjin  mySpan.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', this.listImage[0],
      '" title="', '"/>'
    ].join('');  I add class but when i add css nothing style doesn't add

Comment: well, for your structor... are you use angular 2 component? and if that so, are you set css in your component css file??

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the div or the css of the div, but if you want to change the size of image why don't  you try to write a css that work on img tags which are in div with previewImg.

```
//it is always better to use classes for applying css properties
div#previewImg img {
  border: 3px solid salmon;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: When i use this css in the screen render div with 200x200 and border salomon but image exceed dimension of div because have size 500x200 original. Do you know how to adjust image to div size ?

Comment: div#previewImg {
  border: 3px solid salmon;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

Comment: div#previewImg img {
  width: 100%;
}

Comment: use both together, one works to set the height of outer div and other sets the with of img tag equal to the outer div.

Comment: mySpan.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', this.listImage[0],
      '" width="200px" title="', '"/>'
    ].join('');

Comment: try this in js file